# Object1.position.y = Object2.position.y?

Tags: ios, objective-c, height, sprite-kit

I'm trying to have an object1 (SKSpriteNode) create another object (object2), when it is at a certain height (y-coordinate). I've got all the code I need, except I can't figure out how to properly write:

```
object1.position.y = object2.position.y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position may be a structure.
Try:

```
CGPoint point = CGPointMake(object1.position.x, object2.position.y);
object1.position = point;
```